# UITabBarDelegate or UITabBarControllerDelegate?

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I need to receive a message whenever a user touches a Tab Bar item (even if it corresponds to the currently displayed view).  I'm uncertain as to whether to use the UITabBarDelete protocol, which provides:

```
- (void)tabBar:didSelectItem:
```

Description:

> Sent to the delegate when the user selects a tab bar item.

OR, from the UITabBarControllerDelegate:

```
- (void)tabBarController:didSelectViewController:
```

Description:

> Tells the delegate that the user selected an item in the tab bar.

Seems like either one could be used.  In my case, I need to reload/reinitialize the view associated with true current Tab Button.

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either.

in this case:
- (void)tabBar:didSelectItem:
you'll have to access the corresponding view controller from the viewControllers array.

whereas, in this case:
- (void)tabBarController:didSelectViewController:
you'll get it as an argument.